# regex to convert plain image url to img tags

Tags: php, regex, image, preg-replace, preg-match

I know there are other topics but most of them have different issues.
I am trying to match image urls inside plain text and convert them to  tags but the regex is not working right

`/(http|https):\/\/(\S*)\.(jpg|gif|png)(\?(\S*))?/i`

the above should match an image with url string:

`http://www.example.com/landscape.jpg?w=120`

and without query string:

`http://www.example.com/landscape.jpg`

but it should NOT match this one, **notice the X at the end**:

`http://www.example.com/landscape.jpgx`

that is not an url of an image and my current regex matches that, how can I adjust the regext NOT to match that last URL format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the end that checks the next character after the url *(here, a whitespace character, the end of the string or a punctuation character)*:

```
~https?://\S+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)(?:\?\S*)?(?=\s|$|\pP)~i
```

Comment: Seems to work, thanks, this was my final PHP code, I needed to force http in my case: `$text = preg_replace('/(http|https):\/\/(\S*)\.(jpg|gif|png)(\?(\S*))?(?=\s|$|\pP)/i', '<img src="http://$2.$3$4" border="0" alt="" />', $text, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'/^https?\:\/\/\S+\.(jpg|gif|png)(\?\S+\=\S+)?$/i'
```

Comment: You may want to add `jpeg` and other recognized file extensions for images as well.

Comment: Thanks but the rule doesn't seem to work, the query string should be optional, I think in your rule is `required`.

Comment: `(\?\S+\=\S+)?` should be optional.

Comment: Heya, looks like a great regex... a little explanation would improve your answer though. Don't forget total noobs are on Stack Overflow and may want to learn how you put it together and how it solves the problem... and what may be obvious to you might not be to them. Generally it's Good Form to add a bit more about what you changed and why that solves the problem for the original poster. Otherwise you end up on the "low quality posts" review queue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$string = 'This is image inside text string http://localhost/test/something.jpg?xml=10, http://google.com/logo.png'; 
function _callback($matches){
return '<img src="'.$matches[0].'" />'
}

echo preg_replace_callback('/https?:\/\/(.*?)\.(jpg|png|gif)(\?\w+=\w+)?/i', '_callback', $string);
```